# USING SQL . extract numbers comma separated from string 'HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005'

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

```
'HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005'    
   'HEADER|N156|E1|N7|E122|N4|E5'   
   'HEADER|E0|E1|E2|E3|E4|E5'   
   'HEADER|N0|N1|N2|N3|N4|N5'
   'HEADER|N125'
```

How to extract the numbers in comma-separated format from this stringS?

Expected result:

```
1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005
```

How to extract the numbers with N  or E as suffix/prefix ie.

```
N1000
```

Expected result:

```
1000,1002,1004,1005
```

below regex does not return the result needed. But I want some thing like this

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005', '.*?(\d+)', '\1,'), ',?\.*$', '') from dual
```

the problem here is 
when i want numbers with E OR N

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005', '.*?N(\d+)', '\1,'), ',?\.*$', '') from dual
```

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005', '.*?E(\d+)', '\1,'), ',?\.*$', '') from dual
```

they give  good results for this scenerio

but when i input 'HEADER|N1000|E1001' it gives wrong answer plzzz verify and correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Based on the changes to the question, the original answer is not valid. Instead, the solution is considerably more complex, using a hierarchical query to extract all the numbers from the string and then `LISTAGG` to put back together a list of numbers extracted from each string. To extract all numbers we use this query:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT data, level AS l, REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[NE]\d+', 1, level) AS num FROM test
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, '[NE]\d+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT data, LISTAGG(SUBSTR(num, 2), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY l) AS "All numbers"
FROM cte
GROUP BY data
```

Output (for the new sample data):

```
DATA                                        All numbers
HEADER|E0|E1|E2|E3|E4|E5                    0,1,2,3,4,5
HEADER|N0|N1|N2|N3|N4|N5                    0,1,2,3,4,5
HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005  1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005
HEADER|N125                                 125
HEADER|N156|E1|N7|E122|N4|E5                156,1,7,122,4,5
```

To select only numbers beginning with `E`, we modify the query to replace the `[EN]` in the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` expressions with just `E` i.e.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT data, level AS l, REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, 'E\d+', 1, level) AS num FROM test
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(data, 'E\d+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
DATA                                        E-numbers
HEADER|E0|E1|E2|E3|E4|E5                    0,1,2,3,4,5
HEADER|N0|N1|N2|N3|N4|N5    
HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005  1001,1003
HEADER|N125     
HEADER|N156|E1|N7|E122|N4|E5                1,122,5
```

A similar change can be made to extract numbers commencing with `N`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=37fc14fd4021328c61a0ca95a7ecb5f4)

**Original Answer**

One way to achieve your desired result is to replace a string of characters leading up to a number with that number and a comma, and then replace any characters from the last `,|` to the end of string from the result:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005|', '.*?(\d+)', '\1,'), ',?\|.*$', '') FROM dual
```

Output:

```
1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005
```

To only output the numbers beginning with `N`, we add that to the prefix string before the capture group:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005|', '.*?N(\d+)', '\1,'), ',?\|.*$', '') FROM dual
```

Output:

```
1000,1002,1004,1005
```

To only output the numbers beginning with `E`, we add that to the prefix string before the capture group:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005|', '.*?E(\d+)', '\1,'), ',?\|.*$', '') FROM dual
```

Output:

```
1001,1003
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=19854e96a5c3b950973f4edc84bc5275)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200927/discussion-on-answer-by-nick-using-sql-extract-numbers-comma-separated-from-st).

Comment: @nick i have added the new data sets .for which the query should satisfy

Comment: @CodyGray OP doesn't have enough reputation to visit a chat room... I assume that is why the "would you like to move this discussion to chat" option was never offered.

Comment: @amarenderreddyjali I've updated my answer. It should be a lot more robust now (and works for all the examples you have given)

Comment: @nick thanks but i am thinking of using ur previous answer and ''' select * from (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005|', '.*?E(\d+)', '\1,'), ',?\|.*$', '') as mum FROM dual) where mum like '%|E% '''

Comment: @ NICK can u answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58410091/how-to-make-data-1-2-3-into-list-of-integers-such-that-select-from-employees

Comment: @NICK how can we group 5 pm yesterday to 5 pm today records to todays date
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58497919/12212199?sem=2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what DBMS you are using, but here's one way to do it in Postgres:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CAST('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005|' AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS myValue
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(MyVal FROM 2)
FROM (
  SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(myValue,'\|') MyVal
  FROM cte
) src
WHERE SUBSTRING(MyVal FROM 1 FOR 1) = 'N'
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/38926)

Answer (score 0):

As Far as I have understood the question , you want to extract substrings starting with N from the string, You can try following (And then you can merge the output seperated by commas if needed)

`select  REPLACE(value, 'N', '')
from STRING_SPLIT('HEADER|N1000|E1001|N1002|E1003|N1004|N1005|', '|') 
where value like 'N%'`

OutPut :

> 1000 
>   1002 
>   1004 
>   1005