# how to make data='1,2,3' into list of integers such that select * from employees where emp_id in (data) can work

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting input into data variable   as a string of numbers . but emp_id is integer datatype so ,
when i ran this query it throws error

**i am unable to work "with" or declaring variables  as part of solution . there are similar questions which doesnt satisfy my question.

data is not from a table it is given by some program

so, please dont mark it duplicate**
i want some kind of cast/ inner query such that outer query can succesfully run

```
data='1,2,3'

select *  from employees where emp_id in (data) 
select *  from employees where emp_id in ('1,2,3')
```

this throws error - invalid number
i think we should remove single quotes or cast into list of integers
like 
select *  from employees where emp_id in (1,2,3)

i think data has

```
data='1,2,3'

select *  from employees where emp_id in (data) 
select *  from employees where emp_id in ('1,2,3')
```

expected output is

i want some kind of cast/ inner query such that outer query can succesfully run

such as

```
select *  from employees where emp_id in (your query or cast or function)
```

Comment: @mto this is different from given duplicate questions. i have added details regarding this in the question again . i dont need with statement in the solution and i dont want to create functions of sql . **i want different solutions such as  an inner query sort the problem such that outer query can run properly or using regex**

Comment: you can use this same trick i show here - it'll work with your in subquery https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/03/building-an-object-search-for-sqlcl/

Comment: but what i'm doing is the VERY EXACT thing in the first link/answer posted in the dupe info, you can use that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738359/select-from-table-with-varying-in-list-in-where-clause

Comment: @thatjeffsmith thank you i got the idea  at first i was like they are using " with " statement and  such . but, the query in "with " statement as sub query for my  query was the solution thanks

Comment: select *  from employees where emp_id in (SELECT to_number(trim(regexp_substr('1,2,3', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))) ids
3 FROM temp
4 CONNECT BY instr('1,2,3', ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0)

Comment: glad to hear you got it going - now give a nice upvote to one of those previous answers :)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith can u look tnto this

Comment: how can we group 5 pm yesterday to 5 pm today records to todays date
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58497919/12212199?sem=2

Comment: you're lucky, Connor has already answered your question