# how can we group 5 pm yesterday to 5 pm today records to todays date

Tags: sql, oracle

oracle table

```
id  timestamp                status
1  2019-10-20 12:34:56.000   approved
1  2019-10-22 12:34:56.000   approved
2  2019-10-20 17:34:56.000   approved
2  2019-10-21 12:34:56.000   approved
3  2019-10-23 18:10:10.000   mod_in_ip
3  2019-10-24 11:10:10.000   approved
3  2019-10-24 12:10:10.000   approved
4  2019-10-25 12:10:10.000   approved
4  2019-10-25 18:10:10.000   approved
```

I want to label id's as **new** or **edited**. problem is from the records from  5pm to 5pm is considered working period  **i.e**
 '2019-10-25 17:00:00' to '2019-10-26 17:00:00' would be considered for a working period 
 or
 yesterday's 5 pm to today's 5 pm is a working period.

For example: an id record with yesterday 6:00PM record and today 11AM record should be labeled new
if you look at the table and expected outcome you can get the idea

the expected result/outcome should be

```
1 edited
2 new
3 new
4 edited
```

*initally I tried this but it fails to address the above point*

```
select id,
case
when count(id)<=1 then 'New' 
else 'Edited' End AS prefix 
from(select id,status ,trunc(timestamp) from table 
where 
status='approved' and id in (1,2,3,4)
group by id,status,trunc(timestamp))
group by id
```

the result is

```
1 Edited
2 Edited
3 new
4 new
```

but the expected result is

```
1 edited
2 new
3 new
4 edited
```

I am looking for solutions such as the **innerquery groups records from 5pm to 5pm**  such that outer query can work fine
or an entirely different solution is also feasible

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=abd90416004000043c85316423d64b17

Comment: Why are you say about today/yesterday and show date '2019-10-25 18:10:10'?

Comment: my mistake i thought people could understand that way easier than saying records from '2019-10-25 17:00:00' to '2019-10-26 17:00:00' would be considered for a working period . thanks for pointing it out could u contribute for solution

Comment: Maybe this demo of your problem will help someone: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=abd90416004000043c85316423d64b17

Comment: @VBokšić thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat 5pm to 5pm as the "same" day, it is easy to shift an Oracle date either forward or backward with fractions of day, (eg 5pm can be shifted 7 hours forward to become the start of the 'next' day)

```
SQL> create table ora_table (id number, time_data timestamp, status varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (1  , to_timestamp('2019-10-20 12:34:56.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'approved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (1  , to_timestamp('2019-10-22 12:34:56.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'approved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (2  , to_timestamp('2019-10-20 17:34:56.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'approved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (2  , to_timestamp('2019-10-21 12:34:56.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'approved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (3  , to_timestamp('2019-10-23 18:10:10.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'mod_in_ip');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (3  , to_timestamp('2019-10-24 11:10:10.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'approved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (3  , to_timestamp('2019-10-24 12:10:10.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'approved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (4  , to_timestamp('2019-10-25 12:10:10.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'approved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ora_table values (4  , to_timestamp('2019-10-25 18:10:10.000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'approved');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select id, time_data, trunc(time_data) true_date, trunc(time_data+7/24) mapped_date
  2  from ora_table;

        ID TIME_DATA                          TRUE_DATE MAPPED_DA
---------- ---------------------------------- --------- ---------
         1 20-OCT-19 12.34.56.000000 PM       20-OCT-19 20-OCT-19
         1 22-OCT-19 12.34.56.000000 PM       22-OCT-19 22-OCT-19
         2 20-OCT-19 05.34.56.000000 PM       20-OCT-19 21-OCT-19 <===
         2 21-OCT-19 12.34.56.000000 PM       21-OCT-19 21-OCT-19
         3 23-OCT-19 06.10.10.000000 PM       23-OCT-19 24-OCT-19 <===
         3 24-OCT-19 11.10.10.000000 AM       24-OCT-19 24-OCT-19
         3 24-OCT-19 12.10.10.000000 PM       24-OCT-19 24-OCT-19
         4 25-OCT-19 12.10.10.000000 PM       25-OCT-19 25-OCT-19
         4 25-OCT-19 06.10.10.000000 PM       25-OCT-19 26-OCT-19

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: wow i am such a dummy .thanks for the idea .it just now feels so simple now . i was overthinking about it

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you're looking for:

```sql
WITH cte(id, ts, NewCutoff, Row_Num) AS (
  select 
    id, 
    ts, 
    MIN(
      trunc(ts) + 
      CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) < 17 THEN INTERVAL '00 17' DAY TO HOUR
        ELSE INTERVAL '01 17' DAY TO HOUR -- If time is after 5pm, add an extra day
      END
    ) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS NewCutoff, -- Determine cut-off TS for "new" entries
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts DESC
    ) AS Row_Num -- Order entries by date within "id" group
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT id, CASE WHEN ts < NewCutoff THEN 'new' ELSE 'edited' END AS prefix
FROM cte
WHERE Row_Num = 1 -- Only look at latest entry per id
;
```

You may need to check the end conditions -- i.e. how to handle a `ts` value with exactly 5pm.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69bf6/60)